# Any free, good and extensive word lists for languages other than English?

Tags: dictionary

After considerable search on the Internet, I found a free, good and extensive word list for English that IMHO contains all words (nouns and verbs with their endings as separate entries) one would ever need in common communications: http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/. It has a size of 109582. I like very much to know similar word lists for other languages, in particular for German and French.

Comment: So you're requesting ~7000 word lists?

Comment: @lemontree: The larger the list that contains words with all their different endings and capable of being fairly naturally used in common communications of the people, the better will be the list for purposes of my applications.

Comment: The problem is not with the length of the word lists, but with the sheer amount of possible lists from different languages  there are. You are asking for any word list from any language. That's way too broad for a question on this site; you'd need to make your request more specific.

Comment: @lemontree: I am particularly interested in 3 other languages: German, French and Russian. In French there is in book form from Le Robert: Dictionnaire des mots croisés et mots fléchés which has even 300000 entries but the contents of such resources are not to be freely downloaded.

Comment: Look at aspell. You can extract wordlists for many languages, with all sorts of conjugations and declensions expanded

Answer (score 5):

Yes there are.

There are several choices:

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org) Filter the entries by category language to generate language specific word lists. Lots of additional information (POS, inflection, meanings, translations) are available
- [Wortschatz (Uni Leipzig)](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/), a CLARIN resource, provides corpora in 200 languages. You can download corpora for the language you are interested in and generate wordlists out of it. Good for getting at frequency information and collocations.

Comment: The Wiktionary pages you will want to use are *Category:French lemmas* and *Category:French non-lemma forms* (replace *French* with your language of choice).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/), which is (from [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BabelNet)) "multilingual lexicalized semantic network and ontology...  It was automatically created by linking Wikipedia, to the most popular computational lexicon of the English language, WordNet". By using their API, I think you can easily write a script to extract the words in their database from the languages they offer (Arabic, Chinese, French, German, Greek, Hebrew, Hindi, Italian, Russian, Spanish, ... )

Answer (score 0):

Any general purpose dictionary will help, generally the ones that are published by the language associations.

Comment: Commonly a dictionary entry is a principal word and a list of possible endings, in particular for verbs. I need a list whose individual entries are words with endings, e.g. go, goes, going, went, gone.

Comment: It is hard to find since those endings are produced by grammatical rules, generally people don't bother. Besides this, arabic is a special case, so it has lots of dictionaries/lists like you desired. For starting you can check http://www.almaany.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also see https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/word-lists/ The word lists for English, German, French, Italian, Spanish and Russian. Each language has a longer word list for all words (unrecognized according to PoS categories) and shorter word lists for particular PoS categories, such as German nouns, German verbs, German adjectives, etc.

Comment: Only up to 500 words are available for free, at least in German.

Comment: Yes, there are available only 500 items in several language on that page. However, when you create a 30-day free trial you can download up to 1,000 items in 90+ languages.