# Where to get lists of words in all languages in text format?

Tags: phonetics, list-of-languages

I want to get the list of words in text format in all possible languages and make my deck for ankidriod by exporting alphabetically from Excel.

After that I will try to make a phonetic analysis.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Also an exact duplicate of http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/20494/13238

Comment: Plus, it is way unclear.

Comment: There are close to 7000 languages, most of which have been very poorly studied. What you are asking for is not only impossible, it would be useless to you. As great as Anki is, it won't help you learn 7000 languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know what all currently-existing languages are, and we know even less about all possible languages (I assume you mean human languages). We also do not have a list of all words in even one language, though for English you could get a pretty high percentage. Some languages have very rich and complex morphologies so a verb root could have zillions of inflected forms – some people only care about the lexical root, and not the full sayable word, hence you'd need to specify what you mean by "word". So I am afraid that you are out of luck.

Comment: If I refer to human languages I look for a list of words of each language with the order of a monolingual dictionary for natives, but without its meaning, perfect to add only vocabulary to ankidriod.

Try translating a list of words in English and Spanish into other languages with google translator and the result was not very efficient.